# Best way to shorten UTF8 string based on byte length

Tags: c#, oracle, utf-8, ora-12899

A recent project called for importing data into an Oracle database.  The program that will do this is a C# .Net 3.5 app and I'm using the Oracle.DataAccess connection library to handle the actual inserting.

I ran into a problem where I'd receive this error message when inserting a particular field:

ORA-12899 Value too large for column X

I used `Field.Substring(0, MaxLength);` but still got the error (though not for every record).

Finally I saw what should have been obvious, my string was in ANSI and the field was UTF8.  Its length is defined in bytes, not characters.

This gets me to my question.  What is the best way to trim my string to fix the MaxLength?

My substring code works by character length.  Is there simple C# function that can trim a UT8 string intelligently by byte length (ie not hack off half a character) ?

Comment: P.S. I included the intro just in case anyone Googles my oracle error message in the future.  Hopefully, this will save them some time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are two possible solution - a LINQ one-liner processing the input left to right and a traditional `for`-loop processing the input from right to left. Which processing direction is faster depends on the string length, the allowed byte length, and the number and distribution of multibyte characters and is hard to give a general suggestion. The decision between LINQ and traditional code I probably a matter of taste (or maybe speed).

If speed matters, one could think about just accumulating the byte length of each character until reaching the maximum length instead of calculating the byte length of the whole string in each iteration. But I am not sure if this will work because I don't know UTF-8 encoding well enough. I could theoreticaly imagine that the byte length of a string does not equal the sum of the byte lengths of all characters.

```
public static String LimitByteLength(String input, Int32 maxLength)
{
    return new String(input
        .TakeWhile((c, i) =>
            Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(input.Substring(0, i + 1)) <= maxLength)
        .ToArray());
}

public static String LimitByteLength2(String input, Int32 maxLength)
{
    for (Int32 i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(input.Substring(0, i + 1)) <= maxLength)
        {
            return input.Substring(0, i + 1);
        }
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I love the LINQ example.  That is an elegant solution!

Comment: These both fail if you throw a surrogate pair at them. Try `LimitByteLength("AC", 4)`. This is because they iterate char-by-char, but surrogate pairs take up 2 chars

Comment: In the for-loop example, it would be more readable to loop with "for (Int32 i = input.Length ; i > 0 ; i-- )" and replace the usage "i+1" with "i".

Comment: Few years later. I want to add that this function allocate a lot! 
With long string it will be painful for CG

Answer (score 22):

I think we can do better than naively counting the total length of a string with each addition. LINQ is cool, but it can accidentally encourage inefficient code.  What if I wanted the first 80,000 bytes of a giant UTF string? That's a *lot* of unnecessary counting.  "I've got 1 byte. Now I've got 2. Now I've got 13... Now I have 52,384..."

That's silly.  Most of the time, at least in l'anglais, we can cut *exactly* on that `nth` byte.  Even in another language, we're less than 6 bytes away from a good cutting point.

So I'm going to start from @Oren's suggestion, which is to key off of the leading bit of a UTF8 char value.  Let's start by cutting right at the `n+1th` byte, and use Oren's trick to figure out if we need to cut a few bytes earlier.

**Three possibilities**

If the first byte after the cut has a `0` in the leading bit, I know I'm cutting precisely before a single byte (conventional ASCII) character, and can cut cleanly.

If I have a `11` following the cut, the next byte after the cut is the *start* of a multi-byte character, so that's a good place to cut too!

If I have a `10`, however, I know I'm in the middle of a multi-byte character, and need to go back to check to see where it really starts.

That is, though I want to cut the string after the nth byte, if that n+1th byte comes in the middle of a multi-byte character, cutting would create an invalid UTF8 value.  I need to back up until I get to one that starts with `11` and cut just before it.

**Code**

Notes: I'm using stuff like `Convert.ToByte("11000000", 2)` so that it's easy to tell what bits I'm masking (a little more about bit masking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328309/1028230)).  In a nutshell, I'm `&`ing to return what's in the byte's first two bits and bringing back `0`s for the rest.  Then I check the `XX` from `XX000000` to see if it's `10` or `11`, where appropriate.

I found out *today* that [C# 6.0 might actually support binary representations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546326/1028230), which is cool, but we'll keep using this kludge for now to illustrate what's going on.

The `PadLeft` is just because I'm overly OCD about output to the Console.

So here's a function that'll cut you down to a string that's `n` bytes long or the greatest number less than `n` that's ends with a "complete" UTF8 character.

```
public static string CutToUTF8Length(string str, int byteLength)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    string returnValue = string.Empty;

    if (byteArray.Length > byteLength)
    {
        int bytePointer = byteLength;

        // Check high bit to see if we're [potentially] in the middle of a multi-byte char
        if (bytePointer >= 0 
            && (byteArray[bytePointer] & Convert.ToByte("10000000", 2)) > 0)
        {
            // If so, keep walking back until we have a byte starting with `11`,
            // which means the first byte of a multi-byte UTF8 character.
            while (bytePointer >= 0 
                && Convert.ToByte("11000000", 2) != (byteArray[bytePointer] & Convert.ToByte("11000000", 2)))
            {
                bytePointer--;
            }
        }

        // See if we had 1s in the high bit all the way back. If so, we're toast. Return empty string.
        if (0 != bytePointer)
        {
            returnValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, bytePointer); // hat tip to @NealEhardt! Well played. ;^)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = str;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I initially wrote this as a string extension.  Just add back the `this` before `string str` to put it back into extension format, of course.  I removed the `this` so that we could just slap the method into `Program.cs` in a simple console app to demonstrate.

**Test and expected output**

Here's a good test case, with the output it create below, written expecting to be the `Main` method in a simple console app's `Program.cs`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string testValue = "12345“”67890”";

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        string cutValue = Program.CutToUTF8Length(testValue, i);
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(2) +
            ": " + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(cutValue).ToString().PadLeft(2) +
            ":: " + cutValue);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (byte b in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testValue))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString().PadLeft(3) + " " + (char)b);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Return to end.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output follows.  Notice that the "smart quotes" in `testValue` are three bytes long in UTF8 (though when we write the chars to the console in ASCII, it outputs dumb quotes).  Also note the `?`s output for the second and third bytes of each smart quote in the output.

The first five characters of our `testValue` are single bytes in UTF8, so 0-5 byte values should be 0-5 characters.  Then we have a three-byte smart quote, which can't be included in its entirety until 5 + 3 bytes.  Sure enough, we see that pop out at the call for `8`.Our next smart quote pops out at 8 + 3 = 11, and then we're back to single byte characters through 14.

```
 0:  0::
 1:  1:: 1
 2:  2:: 12
 3:  3:: 123
 4:  4:: 1234
 5:  5:: 12345
 6:  5:: 12345
 7:  5:: 12345
 8:  8:: 12345"
 9:  8:: 12345"
10:  8:: 12345"
11: 11:: 12345""
12: 12:: 12345""6
13: 13:: 12345""67
14: 14:: 12345""678


 49 1
 50 2
 51 3
 52 4
 53 5
226 â
128 ?
156 ?
226 â
128 ?
157 ?
 54 6
 55 7
 56 8
 57 9
 48 0
226 â
128 ?
157 ?
Return to end.
```

So that's kind of fun, and I'm in just before the question's five year anniversary.  Though Oren's description of the bits had a small error, that's *exactly* the trick you want to use.  Thanks for the question; neat.

Comment: Amazing, you did it in O(N)!  Thank you, this is great for long strings.

Comment: You can avoid the final byte[] copy with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, bytePointer)`.

Comment: Note, these days you can use binary literals and avoid all of those `Convert.ToByte` calls

Comment: @canton7 Yep! I put a comment in the original answer, above, saying it looked like those were on the way (turns out it would be C# 7 instead of 6, I think), but kept it like this to make the bytes a tiny bit easier to scan, at least for folks new to the concept. See "_I found out today that C# 6.0 might actually support binary representations..._"

Answer (score 9):

All of the other answers appear to miss the fact that this functionality is already built into .NET, in the [`Encoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoder?view=netframework-4.7.2) class. For bonus points, this approach will also work for other encodings.

```
public static string LimitByteLength(string message, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(message) <= maxLength)
    {
        return message;
    }

    var encoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maxLength];
    char[] messageChars = message.ToCharArray();
    encoder.Convert(
        chars: messageChars,
        charIndex: 0,
        charCount: messageChars.Length,
        bytes: buffer,
        byteIndex: 0,
        byteCount: buffer.Length,
        flush: false,
        charsUsed: out int charsUsed,
        bytesUsed: out int bytesUsed,
        completed: out bool completed);

    // I don't think we can return message.Substring(0, charsUsed)
    // as that's the number of UTF-16 chars, not the number of codepoints
    // (think about surrogate pairs). Therefore I think we need to
    // actually convert bytes back into a new string
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesUsed);
}
```

---

If you're using .NET Standard 2.1+, you can simplify it a bit:

```
public static string LimitByteLength(string message, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(message) <= maxLength)
    {
        return message;
    }

    var encoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maxLength];
    encoder.Convert(message.AsSpan(), buffer.AsSpan(), false, out _, out int bytesUsed, out _);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesUsed);
}
```

---

None of the other answers account for extended grapheme clusters, such as `‍`. This is composed of 4 Unicode scalars (, , a zero-width joiner, and ), so you need knowledge of the Unicode standard to avoid splitting it in the middle and producing  or .

In **.NET 5** onwards, you can write this as:

```
public static string LimitByteLength(string message, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(message) <= maxLength)
    {
        return message;
    }
    
    var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(message);
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    int lengthBytes = 0;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        lengthBytes += Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(enumerator.GetTextElement());
        if (lengthBytes <= maxLength)
        {
            result.Append(enumerator.GetTextElement()); 
        }
    }
    
    return result.ToString();
}
```

(This same code runs on earlier versions of .NET, but due to a bug it won't produce the correct result before .NET 5).

Comment: Oh, it's been a while since I've looked at this one, though I remembered it was fun to answer in 2014. This is neat... ["_extended grapheme clusters_" are covered in more detail here](https://tonsky.me/blog/unicode/) (h/t [Michael Tsai](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2023/10/05/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-must-know-about-unicode-in-2023/)). I need to update my answer! That's cool -- "the growth of digital infrastructure". UTF-8 is starting to feel like [the NYC subway system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpPhJu0HUn8).

Answer (score 7):

Shorter version of [ruffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470707/1722660). Takes advantage of [the design of UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description):

```
    public static string LimitUtf8ByteCount(this string s, int n)
    {
        // quick test (we probably won't be trimming most of the time)
        if (Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s) <= n)
            return s;
        // get the bytes
        var a = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        // if we are in the middle of a character (highest two bits are 10)
        if (n > 0 && ( a[n]&0xC0 ) == 0x80)
        {
            // remove all bytes whose two highest bits are 10
            // and one more (start of multi-byte sequence - highest bits should be 11)
            while (--n > 0 && ( a[n]&0xC0 ) == 0x80)
                ;
        }
        // convert back to string (with the limit adjusted)
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a, 0, n);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If a UTF-8 *byte* has a zero-valued high order bit, it's the beginning of a character. If its high order bit is 1, it's in the 'middle' of a character. The ability to detect the beginning of a character was an explicit design goal of UTF-8.

Check out the Description section of the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you show me a C# example? Does this mean that there isn't any built in functionality to handle this need? It seems like a common problem.

Comment: If you have a C# string, you could use Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(string) to get the precise byte count. You can trim characters from the end of the string, if you need to, until the byte count fits the limit.

Comment: Not *quite* right. If it's a single byte, it does start with `0`, but if its high bit is `1`, it could be the leading or "middle" (let's say "following") byte of a multi-byte character. The leading byte starts with `11` and the following bytes in the multi-byte character start with `10`. So if your leading bit is `1`, you're in a multi-byte character, but **not necessarily the "middle"**. From the 'pedia: *The leading byte has two or more high-order 1s followed by a 0, while continuation bytes all have '10' in the high-order position.*

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you need the database column to be declared in terms of bytes?  That's the default, but it's not a particularly useful default if the database character set is variable width.  I'd strongly prefer declaring the column in terms of characters.

```
CREATE TABLE length_example (
  col1 VARCHAR2( 10 BYTE ),
  col2 VARCHAR2( 10 CHAR )
);
```

This will create a table where COL1 will store 10 bytes of data and col2 will store 10 characters worth of data.  Character length semantics make far more sense in a UTF8 database.

Assuming you want all the tables you create to use character length semantics by default, you can set the initialization parameter `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` to CHAR.  At that point, any tables you create will default to using character length semantics rather than byte length semantics if you don't specify CHAR or BYTE in the field length.

Comment: Great idea.  I don't control the Oracle DB, but I will suggest that.  Maybe it was just an oversight.  This would be the best solution to my problem if they're willing to make the change.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Oren Trutner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130689/oren-trutner) here are two more solutions to the problem:
here we count the number of bytes to remove from the end of the string according to each character at the end of the string, so we don't evaluate the entire string in every iteration.

```
string str = "朣楢琴执执 瑩浻牡楧硰执执獧浻牡楧敬瑦 瀰 絸朣杢执獧扻捡杫潲湵 潣" 
int maxBytesLength = 30;
var bytesArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
int bytesToRemove = 0;
int lastIndexInString = str.Length -1;
while(bytesArr.Length - bytesToRemove > maxBytesLength)
{
   bytesToRemove += Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new char[] {str[lastIndexInString]} );
   --lastIndexInString;
}
string trimmedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesArr,0,bytesArr.Length - bytesToRemove);
//Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(trimmedString);//get the actual length, will be <= 朣楢琴执执 瑩浻牡楧硰执执獧浻牡楧敬瑦 瀰 絸朣杢执獧扻捡杫潲湵 潣潬昣昸昸慢正
```

And an even more efficient(and maintainable) solution:
get the string from the bytes array according to desired length and cut the last character because it might be corrupted

```
string str = "朣楢琴执执 瑩浻牡楧硰执执獧浻牡楧敬瑦 瀰 絸朣杢执獧扻捡杫潲湵 潣" 
int maxBytesLength = 30;    
string trimmedWithDirtyLastChar = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str),0,maxBytesLength);
string trimmedString = trimmedWithDirtyLastChar.Substring(0,trimmedWithDirtyLastChar.Length - 1);
```

The only downside with the second solution is that we might cut a perfectly fine last character, but we are already cutting the string, so it might fit with the requirements.
Thanks to [Shhade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873002/shhade-slman) who thought about the second solution

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution based on binary search:

```
public string LimitToUTF8ByteLength(string text, int size)
{
    if (size <= 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    int maxLength = text.Length;
    int minLength = 0;
    int length = maxLength;

    while (maxLength >= minLength)
    {
        length = (maxLength + minLength) / 2;
        int byteLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text.Substring(0, length));

        if (byteLength > size)
        {
            maxLength = length - 1;
        }
        else if (byteLength < size)
        {
            minLength = length + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return text.Substring(0, length); 
        }
    }

    // Round down the result
    string result = text.Substring(0, length);
    if (size >= Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return text.Substring(0, length - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string LimitByteLength3(string input, Int32 maxLenth)
    {
        string result = input;

        int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(input);
        if (byteCount > maxLenth)
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, maxLenth);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: this can corrupt the last character and in fact does not work as recoded byte array will again axceed the limit