# Byte-based length of CLR string

Tags: .net, string, oracle, varchar

**Short version of the question:** Is there a way of counting how many bytes will it take to store the characters of a string in a `VARCHAR(n)` column in an Oracle database?

**Longer version:** The following Oracle SQL script will fail at the third statement. It will try to insert 10 characters in a `VARCHAR(10)` column; however, one of these characters is the A with an acute accent.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (NAME VARCHAR(10) NULL);

INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (NAME) VALUES ('abcdefghij');
--1 rows inserted.

INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (NAME) VALUES ('ábcdefghij');
--ORA-12899: value too large for column "ACME"."TESTTABLE"."NAME" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)
```

My C# application stores strings in an Oracle database and I can't just change the column type to `NVARCHAR2(10)`, which would work. The application is expected to trim any larger string to a limit of 10 characters, so Oracle won't complain about its length. But a `String.Length`-based trim is a very naif strategy: it would blindly leave *"ábcdefghij"* intact with all its 10 CLR characters.

How can I detect that *'á'* will take 2 bytes in the database row so I can trim the string to *"ábcdefghi"* before issuing the `INSERT` statement?

**EDIT:** this question is similar to [Best way to shorten UTF8 string based on byte length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225052/best-way-to-shorten-utf8-string-based-on-byte-length)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the encoding you have Oracle set to use. You convert the string instance into a byte array using the corresponding `System.Text.Encoding` instance, such as `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`. (You're looking for the "GetBytes" method)

Comment: This is the answer that best fits the situation, because I can only do so much on the database side of the problem. I'm limited to changing the C# app only. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 5):

Oracle function `length(string)` returns number of characters, `lengthb(string)` returns number of bytes.

Comment: +1 -- this is the only answer that will work regardless of Oracle's encoding configuration.

Comment: I didn't know about the `lengthb()` function, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `VARCHAR2(10)` allocates 10 bytes of storage which may or may not equate to 10 characters depending on the database character set and the data.  You can, however, declare the column so that it will always store 10 characters.

When you are using a variable-width character set, you almost always want to declare the column using character-length semantics `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)`.  Then you can always store 10 characters whether you happen to have some characters that require more than 1 byte of storage.

If you're stuck declaring columns using byte-length semantics for some reason, you could use the `LENGTHB` or `VSIZE` function to return the length of the string in bytes.

```
select lengthb('ábcdefghij'), vsize('ábcdefghij')
  from dual;
```

will return 11 for both columns of the result.

Comment: `+1` for `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)`

Comment: `VARCHAR2` would be a very nice idea if the DBA had thought about international characters before! And he should have done it, by the way. We have too many accented characters in Portuguese.

Comment: @Humberto - `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` are synonyms-- you can happily declare a `VARCHAR(10 CHAR)` column if you'd like (or alter an existing `VARCHAR(10 BYTE)` column to `VARCHAR(10 CHAR)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the lenght in bytes of the string like this:

```
UTF8Encoding Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] UTF8String = Encoding.GetBytes("ábcdefghij");
int StringLenght = UTF8String.Length
```

In fact, for your example, it returns 11.

Comment: +1 for code example of my answer. Though you should probably use the static Encoding.UTF8 instance rather than creating new UTF8Encoding instances. (That will result in less GC overhead)