# getting warning Value of Order Description element has been truncated. in paypal

Tags: paypal

I am getting below the warring message some time in paypal.  But same time it is working fine. I am passing $200 means working good but  $30 means below the warning message was displayed

**Array ( [TOKEN] => EC-8JN325950R8891611 [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-12-28T07:30:02Z [CORRELATIONID] => ef1922a5aa68a [ACK] => SuccessWithWarning [VERSION] => 65 [BUILD] => 18308778 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10433 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details. [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Value of OrderDescription element has been truncated. [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Warning )**

can you  help me to solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal's PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESC parameter only accepts 127 characters.

If you pass more than that it will still accept the payment and process the transaction, but it will return the warning that your data was truncated like you're getting.

If you look at your raw request you'll see that you must have a value longer than 127 characters in that parameter.

Comment: Hi Andrew Angell

Thanks for your update .  Now i reduced the description limit , it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal's PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESC field, although it says it has a limit of 127 characters in the PayPal documentation, ACTUALLY seems to  have a limit of 127 bytes.
There is an incorrect assumption by PayPal that 127 characters = 127 bytes.
We found when descriptions contained <= 127 unicode characters, we still ran into this validation issue.

Our solution was to add a function that truncated the provided string based on byte length.
C# examples: [Best way to shorten UTF8 string based on byte length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225052/best-way-to-shorten-utf8-string-based-on-byte-length)

Comment: Thanks was confused why we were getting a SUCCESSWITHWARNING even after truncating the string length to 127, but once I truncated the UTF8 bytes it worked as intended!