# C# binary constants representation

Tags: c#, binary, format, constants, representation

I am really stumped on this one. In C# there is a hexadecimal constants representation format as below :

```
int a = 0xAF2323F5;
```

is there a binary constants representation format?

Comment: What do you mean?
const int a = 2938315765;

Comment: Thank you, I guess your result is correct but I was looking for systematical solution. Should I post a question o stackoverflow for each binary constant I need to convert?

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594720/c-binary-literals

Comment: Good pointer, didn't know to search for "literal" although I should. Maybe Jeff was right about the search algoritm sucking a little (39%?)

Comment: Posted my answer in the linked thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594720/c-binary-literals/3776553#3776553.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of C#7 you can represent a binary literal value in code:

```
private static void BinaryLiteralsFeature()
{
    var employeeNumber = 0b00100010; //binary equivalent of whole number 34. Underlying data type defaults to System.Int32
    Console.WriteLine(employeeNumber); //prints 34 on console.
    long empNumberWithLongBackingType = 0b00100010; //here backing data type is long (System.Int64)
    Console.WriteLine(empNumberWithLongBackingType); //prints 34 on console.
    int employeeNumber_WithCapitalPrefix = 0B00100010; //0b and 0B prefixes are equivalent.
    Console.WriteLine(employeeNumber_WithCapitalPrefix); //prints 34 on console.
}
```

Further information can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1156167/Csharp-Version-Introduction-to-new-language-featur).

Answer (score 8):

Nope, no binary literals in C#.  You can of course parse a string in binary format using Convert.ToInt32, but I don't think that would be a great solution.

```
int bin = Convert.ToInt32( "1010", 2 );
```

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a few hours but this being the first answer, if it proves true, it will be chosen as the official answer. Thank you.

Comment: True, that works, and it is useful in most cases. Unfortunately it does not work if you're using it in a `switch(myVariable) { case bin: Console.WriteLine("value detected"); break; }` statement, since `case` only allows constants.

Comment: It's possible now as `0b1010` as of C# 7 (more than 5 years ago as of this comment.) See answer by @Luis

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use an extension method:

```
public static int ToBinary(this string binary)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32( binary, 2 );
}
```

However, whether this is wise I'll leave up to you (given the fact it will operate on any string).

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio 2017, binary literals like 0b00001 are supported.

Comment: Is this a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193863)?

Comment: sorry, but i want to figure out that the newly released VS 2017 supports such a usage,hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see how repeating something that was already explained much better in the accepted answer could ever help anyone.