# Binary notation for writing bits - C#

Tags: c#, binary, bit, notation

There are some notations to write numbers in C# that tell if what you wrote is float, double, integer and so on.

So I would like to write a binary number, how do I do that?

Say I have a byte:

```
byte Number = 10011000 //(8 bits)
```

How should I write it without having the trouble to know that 10011000 in binary = 152 in decimal?

P.S.: Parsing a string is completely out of question (I need performance)

Comment: What's wrong with `byte Number = 152; // 10011000`? Hex, i.e. `0x98`, should also work, and is easier to work out.

Comment: ... or working with hex-values, like: byte Number = 0x98; // 10011000

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/594725/939213

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as of <del>c# 6</del> c# 7 you can use `0b` prefix to get binary similar to the `0x` for hex

```
int x           = 0b1010000; //binary value of 80
int seventyFive = 0b1001011; //binary value of 75
```

give it a shot

Comment: was planned for c# 6, but is not part of the release. It was added to C# in version 7. This means you need Visual Studio 2017 at least.

Answer (score 6):

You can write this:

```
int binaryNotation = 0b_1001_1000;
```

In C# 7.0 and later, you can use the underscore '_' as a digit seperator including decimal, binary, or hexadecimal notation, to improve legibility.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do it other than parsing a string, I'm afraid:

```
byte number = (byte) Convert.ToInt32("10011000", 2);
```

Unfortunately you will be unable to assign constant values like that, of course.

If you find yourself doing that a lot, I guess you could write an extension method on string to make things more readable:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static byte AsByte(this string self)
    {
        return (byte)Convert.ToInt32(self, 2);
    }
}
```

Then the code would look like this:

```
byte number = "10011000".AsByte();
```

I'm not sure that would be a good idea though...

Personally, I just use hex initializers, e.g.

```
byte number = 0x98;
```