# C# Visual Studio binary literal syntax error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, binary, syntax-error, literals

I have some problem with C# binary literals in Visual Studio. When I try to set some variable to binary literal I get syntax error CS1002 (need ';'). How to solve this problem? There is no problems with hexadecimal literals.

```
byte b = 0b00000000; // error
```

**Screenshot of error**

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: It's looks like you are using old version of c#. `0b` literals are only available starting from version 7. More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546326/4685428) answer

Comment: @AleksAndreev Okay, I will try to change my c# version. Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# binary literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594720/c-sharp-binary-literals)